# Running python mapreduce for multiple files

Tags: python, linux, mapreduce, cat, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to implement python mapreduce for multiple files in directory, so that it will take folder and string as an argument and list files with the frequency of that string within that files. The output should be like that:
Filename  Output
--------  --------------
x.txt     8
y.txt     12

I have tried to implement it but when I run it with command below:
    cat /home/habil/Downloads/hadoop_test/*.txt  | python mapper.py "AA" | python reducer.py 
It gives me "AA 479" which are the frequency in all 5 files

This is my mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import textwrap
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join




#Argument of the path
#folderPath = sys.argv[2]
#onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(sys.argv[2]) if isfile(join(sys.argv[2], f))]
# Get the string sequence from the user
searchWord = sys.argv[1]
# Length of the word
searchWordLength = len(sys.argv[1])

# helper Function
def locations_of_substring(string, substring):
    """Return a list of locations of a substring."""
    substring_length = len(substring)
    def recurse(locations_found, start):
        location = string.find(substring, start)
        if location != -1:
            return recurse(locations_found + [location], location+substring_length)
        else:
            return locations_found

    return recurse([], 0)

#--- get all lines from stdin ---
for line in sys.stdin:
    #--- remove leading and trailing whitespace---
    line = line.strip()
    temp = locations_of_substring(line, searchWord)
    if len(temp) != 0:
        for count in temp:
            print '%s\t%s' % (line[count:count+searchWordLength], "1")
```

And below is my reducer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

# maps words to their counts
word2count = {}

# input comes from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()

    # parse the input we got from mapper.py
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
    # convert count (currently a string) to int
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    try:
        word2count[word] = word2count[word]+count
    except:
        word2count[word] = count

# write the tuples to stdout
# Note: they are unsorted
for word in word2count.keys():
    print '%s\t%s'% ( word, word2count[word])
```

How can I get the desired result, so that it will run for each file in the directory, once and print seperate results. Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.